# Keithley 2750 Multimeter and 7702 MUX card -221 "settings conflict"

Tags: python

I am programming the Keithley 2750 multimeter with a 7702 MUX card and 3740 relay card for a product testing machine.

Here is the code:

```
ROUT:MULT:OPEN (@101:142)
SENS:FUNC 'RES', <clist>
ROUT:SCAN  <clist>
SAMP:COUN 5
ROUT:SCAN:TSO IMM
ROUT:SCAN:LSEL INT
READ?
ROUT:MULT:OPEN (@101:142)
```

I get a `-221: "Settings conflict"` error when running the code multiple times while measuring different channels.
When I was opening the channels with `ROUT:OPEN:ALL`, everything was fine, but now I get the mentioned error.

The thing is, I cannot use `:OPEN:ALL` because that would also open the relays, which is not an option because testing machinery will be hooked up to them. But I am opening all channels of the MUX before the measurement, so I don't know why I get the error.

How could I modify the code to make it work?

**edit:**
I have working TSP code for this functionality, I would just like to implement it for a multimeter that doesn't support TSC.

```
scan.mode=scan.MODE_OPEN_SELECTIVE
...
scan.create('<clist>', '<configuration>')
state = scan.execute(buffer)
printbuffer(1, buffer.n, buffer)
buffer.clear()
```

The scan works in TSP because of the `scan.MODE_OPEN_SELECTIVE`, which opens all the measurement channels but not the relay channels. I cannot seem to achieve the same with SCPI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying here because I haven't signed up for Tek forum yet.
7702 card 41 and 42 channels available only current function. So, you get the -221 settings conflict(@141 function RES). Also need change  values.
How about below commands?

```
 ROUT:MULT:OPEN (@101:140)
 SENS:FUNC 'RES', <clist>
 ROUT:SCAN  <clist>
 SAMP:COUN 5
 ROUT:SCAN:TSO IMM
 ROUT:SCAN:LSEL INT
 READ?
 ROUT:MULT:OPEN (@101:140)
```

Comment: Current is not measured on channels 41 and 42 so that should not be a problem, `<clist>` never includes them. The error is only thrown after the 1st measurement, presumably because the 2750 has no way of knowing that no channels are closed (connected) to the multimeter. As I said, the error is not thrown if all channels are opened with `ROUT:OPEN:ALL`.